# Web browser based Xpra client?

Tags: linux, xserver

Xpra has been a great tool for me to stream X applications over the web. I am looking for a web based Xpra client for my current project. Does one exist already? How hard would it be to implement one to embed it in a web browser? Any pointers please...

Answer (score 0):

The html5 client and server [documented here](http://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Clients/HTML5) is now included in all official xpra releases. Note that some downstream distributions do not include it, or break the packaging.